# Social login on registration page for Stormpath

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stormpath, express-stormpath

I really hope this is my last question on the Stormpath API for a while. Making the switch from C# and PHP to node has been somewhat challenging.

I am trying to implement social login on the registration page. The pre-built option places it on the Login page only.

Rendering the page and adding elements to the Jade view is simple enough, but I need to get an oauthStateToken. Now I looked at how the login.js code does this:

```
        var oauth = require('../oauth');        
        var oauthStateToken = oauth.common.resolveStateToken(req, res);
        var formActionUri = (config.web.login.uri + (nextUri ? ('?next=' + nextUri) : ''));

        var hasSocialProviders = _.some(config.web.social, function (socialProvider) {
          return socialProvider.enabled;
        });

        extend(options, {
          form: form,
          formActionUri: formActionUri,
          oauthStateToken: oauthStateToken,
          hasSocialProviders: hasSocialProviders
        });
```

So essentially it calls the oath files and goes through the code, theoretically, I could do something similar on register.js - essentially (just sample code):

```
    var oauth = require('../oauth');
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var hasSocialProviders = _.some(config.web.social, function (socialProvider) {
          return socialProvider.enabled;
    });
    var oauthStateToken = '';
    if (hasSocialProviders) {
          oauthStateToken = oauth.common.resolveStateToken(req, res);
    }

    helpers.render(req, res, view, {
        form: helpers.sanitizeFormData(req.body),
        formModel: viewModel.form
        oauthStateToken : oauthStateToken,
        hasSocialProviders: hasSocialProviders
    });
```

But of course I wouldn't want to meddle with the core files, and was thinking about creating a middleware function, something like `app.use('/register', callFunction, router);` but I am having some difficulty in conceptualizing how that would work. I seem to understand how stormpath lets me generate an oauth token which I store as a cookie using JWT but I'm having a hard time putting it together into working code without replicating a lot of code already existent in the library.

I can even kinda of get it working by using the REST API but I would like to use it within the express-stormpath library. So some explanation in the context of express-stormpath library would also be enlightening. OR am I overthinking this, should I just fork the library, make the changes to register.js and try for a push upstream?

Thanks again folks,

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the question!

I’ve found a way to work around this in your application, without modifying the express-stormpath library.  You’ll need to add a route handler for your registration route, and in that route handler you’ll have to manually do the work to get the `oAuthStateToken` setup, then call `next()` to let express-stormpath continue handling the request for the registration page.  Here’s what that looks like:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var oauth = require('express-stormpath/lib/oauth');

// create your express server, 'app'

app.use('/register', cookieParser(), function (req, res, next) {
  var oauthStateToken = oauth.common.resolveStateToken(req, res);
  req.app.get('stormpathConfig').templateContext = {
    oauthStateToken: oauthStateToken
  };
  next();
});

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  // .. other config options
  web: {
    register: {
      view: 'views/register.jade'  // path to your custom registration file
    }
  }
}));
```

I hope this helps!  This certainly could be easier, this is a good feature request for the library.

Comment: Hey, so yep - I had tried something similar but it seemed like not a good idea to reference functions in the library like that (specifically the oauth library directly and not through a documented API).

I'll try it out and see report back. I will also fork the code and try a pull request with you folks (feel free to decline, as you likely have thought of better ways of doing it). It seems like a common enough use case where you'd want to make sure your users are aware that they don't have to sign up and can just log in directly with social logins.

Also thanks! You guys are champs.

Comment: Two things that I had to change:

`oauthStateToken` instead of `oAuthStateToke`

And `app.use` instead of `app.get` - though I don't think that matters in this case at all.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed the example accordingly.  I'm glad you were able to get it working :)

Comment: Almost works - if you visit the registration page, use the social login, and then visit the login page then the login page stops working with a `Invalid state token provided.` - so I compared it to my earlier modification of core files branch, that one didn't - so maybe something about setting it as the templateContext?